# Can I return immediately when meets None while function chaining?

Tags: function, methods, rust

[Problem](https://exercism.org/tracks/rust/exercises/luhn).
I'm curious about this because if it can, I don't need if thing in this code I think.
I want that especially `.filter_map(|ch| ch.to_digit(10))`.
`ch.to_digit()` returns None if  ch is not digit. then I want return false.
If I can do this, I think I don't need `if !code.chars().all(|ch| ch.is_digit(10) || ch.is_whitespace())` this check.
(I just wanted to know can I do that if checks within chaining.)

If it's not allowed, is there some way to do exception check in function chain?
Thanks.

```rust
/// Check a Luhn checksum.
pub fn is_valid(code: &str) -> bool {
    if code.trim().len() <= 1 {
        return false;
    }
    if !code.chars().all(|ch| ch.is_digit(10) || ch.is_whitespace()) {
        return false;
    }

    code.chars()
        .rev()
        .filter_map(|ch| ch.to_digit(10))
        .enumerate()
        .map(|( i, n)|
            match i % 2 {
                0 => n,
                _ if n == 9 => n,
                _ => (n * 2) % 9,
            }
        )
        .sum::<u32>() % 10 == 0
}
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question please? I don't get your question, sorry. What is your question? What do you want to achieve? Maybe write some pseudo code or similar.

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/68537 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I return immediately when meets None while function chaining?

Not really. You could `map` to an `Option` (instead of `filter_map`) then `collect` the `Iterator<Option<_>>` to an `Option<Vec<_>>`:

```rust
let items = vec![0_u16, 1, 2];

let res: Option<Vec<u16>> = items
    .iter()
    .map(|x| x.checked_add(1))
    .collect();

assert_eq!(res, Some(vec![1, 2, 3]));

let res: Option<Vec<u16>> = items
    .iter()
    .map(|x| x.checked_sub(1))
    .collect();

assert_eq!(res, None);
```

then you'd bail if you have a `None` at the end.

But in all honestly I'd just use a bog-standard `for` loop e.g.:

```rust
let mut sum = 0;
for (i, n) = code.chars().rev().map(|ch| ch.to_digit(10)).enumerate() {
    sum += match (i % 2, n) {
        (_, None) => return false;
        (0, Some(n)) => n,
        (_, Some(9)) => 9,
        (_, Some(n)) => (n * 2) % 9,
    }
}
sum % 10 == 0
```

> If it's not allowed, is there some way to do exception check in function chain?

Not sure what you mean.

Comment: "is there some way to do exception check in function chain?" In languages like Swift, it would be very common to use `throw` here to abort early. I believe that's what the OP is referring to. (But in Rust, I agree the for loop is definitely the best approach.)

Comment: `take_while` would allow to stop immediately

Comment: @Stargateur the goal is to signal that the sequence is not valid in that case, as far as I can think `take_while` wouldn't do so unless you also `map` to an `Option`, following which you'd still have to iterate the entire thing to find out that there was a `None`, at which point I don't see what the gain is compared to skipping the `take_while`.

Comment: @Stargateur the original poster explicitly says that their goal is to remove the pre-check over the sequence (lines 5-7), so it's not a guess, the entire point is to avoid iterating twice.

Comment: I agree with @Masklinn, but I don't understand why returning in loop is fine and not in chained method.

Comment: @HeathKim because Rust does not have non-local `return` so you can only `return` from one function at a time. For a `return` to "carry", it has to be specifically provided for by the higher order function's API. That is essentially what [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold) (which I'd forgotten about) is designed for, and why it is specifically documented as short-circuiting.

Answer (score 1):

You can with [`try_fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold):

```
pub fn is_valid(code: &str) -> bool {
    code.chars()
        .rev()
        .try_fold((0, 0), |acc, ch|
            // `acc.0` enumerates the valid digits
            // `acc.1` accumulates the sum
            if ch.is_whitespace() {
                Some (acc)
            } else {
                ch.to_digit (10).map (|n|
                    match acc.0 % 2 {
                        0 => (acc.0+1, acc.1 + n),
                        _ if n == 9 => (acc.0+1, acc.1 + n),
                        _ => (acc.0+1, acc.1 + (n*2)%9),
                    })
            })
        .map (|acc| acc.1 % 10 == 0)
        .unwrap_or (false)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3198c1ba8087290b1e2cfbe11cf25aea)

However for readability's sake, I would go with @Masklinn's straightforward `for` loop.